# Unable to deploy to heroku due to requirements.txt error

Tags: flask, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy a flask app to heroku for the first time. when i do git push heroku master i get the following error

[app.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0kAD.png)

`cp: cannot stat '/tmp/cache/requirements.txt': No such file or directory`

my procfile looks like this
`web: gunicorn app.py`

runtime.txt
`python-3.6.1`

requirements.txt

```
bokeh==2.1.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
cssmin==0.2.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Assets==2.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
httplib2==0.18.1
idna==2.9
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
jsmin==2.2.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
libsass==0.20.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.19.0
opensecrets-crpapi==0.2.2
packaging==20.4
pandas==1.0.5
Pillow==7.2.0
pylint==2.5.3
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-dotenv==0.13.0
pytz==2020.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.24.0
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
toml==0.10.1
tornado==6.0.4
typed-ast==1.4.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.2
urllib3==1.25.9
webassets==2.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
whitenoise==5.1.0
wrapt==1.12.1
```

here is the full error log

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: cp: cannot stat '/tmp/cache/requirements.txt': No such file or directory
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.11
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Obtaining file:///tmp/cache (from -r /tmp/cache/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/cache/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/cache/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/cache/
remote:            Complete output (8 lines):
remote:            running egg_info
remote:            creating finalproject.egg-info
remote:            writing finalproject.egg-info/PKG-INFO
remote:            writing dependency_links to finalproject.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
remote:            writing requirements to finalproject.egg-info/requires.txt
remote:            writing top-level names to finalproject.egg-info/top_level.txt
remote:            writing manifest file 'finalproject.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote:            error: package directory 'application' does not exist
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

````py
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py')

##where to find the database and initialize SQLAlchemy
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///congress.sqlite3'
db = SQLAlchemy(app) 

##option to tell SQLALchemy that we’re way too lazy to do that, and for every model it should just 
#look at the columns that already exist in the table. This is called reflecting
db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)

class Congress(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sen'
    __table_args__ = { 'extend_existing': True }
    id = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True) 


## access sass
app.wsgi_app = SassMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
    'app': ('static/assets/sass', 'app/static/assets/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css', 'app/static/assets/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css')
})

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Custom filter
app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd

from app import routes```
````

Comment: Can you show the structure of your project directory? It genrally happens when there is something wrong with your procfile.

Comment: Ive included a link to a pic of my project directory. ty

Comment: Your Procfile must look like this `web: gunicorn app:nameofyourapp` nameofyourapp is the name you used in app.py

Comment: i tried app:app.py also app:app and unfortunately neither worked. do you have any other suggestions

Comment: Please show your app py file. Also I am assuming that you are using your app.py file to run the flask app

Comment: my app.py file just says from app import app

Comment: So you also need to create the instance of your app. If you are not sure how to do that post the code of your init.py

Comment: @Aditya ive included my init.py, ty

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because you have not call the run function in your `app.py` file i.e you have imported the app but have not told the flask what to do with that app.
As you have mentioned your `app.py` file looks like this:

```
from app import app
```

But you need to specify what to do with the app. So your `app.py` must look like this:

```
from app import app

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

And `Procfile` must look like this:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: i tried all your instructions and unfortunately im still getting the same error message. the error, the error on line 7 seems to indicate something going wrong with setup.py. Im not entirely sure how to remedy this. thank you for your help tho

Comment: You have 2 files setup.py as well as settings.py. What does setup.py is doing. If you think setup.py file is the cause of the problem, try removing that file and then deploy it. Or post your entire project in some site like GitHub so that I or someone else can see your entire code and can help you in better way. By the way sorry for not being able to help you

Comment: I have just realised that you might forgetting to commit the changes that you have done. Try to commit those changes and then run `git push heroku master`

Comment: I am committing the changes. I realized i have been running the mac OS installation of python this whole time and that might have something to do with it. Not entirely sure tho. Ill upload my repository shortly

Comment: ive added a link to my github

Comment: I created a new directory and reinstalled a new venv and was able to deploy a build onto Heroku but now running to other errors once i get passed the first page lol.